# Generic factorial, how to implement

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to implement a factorial function, using recursion. I try to make use of generics, but can't figure out how to handle the return of the 1.

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable> T calculateFactorial(T n)  {
        if (n.compareTo(0)==0)  {
            return 1; //error
        }

        return n*calculateFactorial(n-1);
    }
```

I get a `incompatible types: int cannot be converted to T`error on `return 1` line.

Also if I simply replace `return 1` with `return n`, I get a `error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'` error on `return n*calculateFactorial(n-1)` line.

How should I handle this and what is a good practice on doing it? Should generics be used at such functions?

Comment: Best practice is not to try to do it generically. Use `BigInteger`, since primitives (/wrapped primitives) quickly overflow or lose precision.

Comment: You could accept an appropriately-typed 1 as an additional method argument.  You cannot dynamically *compute* an appropriate 1 based on the type parameter.

Comment: You can safely define n as an int. Anything bigger will overflow your memory.

Comment: @John and an appropriate function for "minus 1", and an appropriate binary operator for "multiply".

Comment: Yes indeed, @Andy.  Quite a lot of bother, really.

Comment: But factorial only makes sense for integers, why using a generic type? If the thing is `Integer` vs `BigInteger`, use an overloaded method

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to use the same `T` both for input and output because it overflows easily the primitive values. You can solve this using one more method.

```
public static <T extends Number> BigInteger calculateFactorial(T t) {
    return factorial(new BigInteger(t.toString()));
}

private static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    if (n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    } else {
        return n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    }
}
```

Check whether all the outputs are correct. They all should print `24` below.

```
System.out.println(calculateFactorial(4));
System.out.println(calculateFactorial(4L));
System.out.println(calculateFactorial(new BigInteger("4")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since factorial is only defined for integers, it would be easier to just use integers instead of generics.  But if you want to use T anyway as an exercise, you need to return a T object:

```
    T one = (T) new Integer(1);
    if (n.compareTo(0)==0)  {
        return one;
    }
```

You'll also need to define your own multiply and subtract, since math operations are not available on generics.